# How to take pictures without user input with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am making an application that will take pictures every 1 seconds.

The pictures must be taken without the user input (the application will be remotly controlled and run on a flying drone).

I have looked at Xamarin.Media plugin, but the method :

```
CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "Sample",
    Name = "test.jpg"
});
```

needs user input (it opens the camera app and wait for the user to take the picture).

I have also looked at Android.Hardware.Camera, but everything there looks deprecated.

Is there a way to do this on Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: You will want to use the android.hardware.camera2 (this replaced the deprecated camera framework/package)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to take pictures? You could also work with a live video stream. 
Just use camera2 like SushiHangover already stated. It works both for pictures and live video.

Or you could use the google vision api. It could come in handy if you want to expand your code with tracking of people and faces.
Here is a quick example to get you started. You can skip the whole face tracking part if you don't need to use it:
https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-face-tracking-live-recognition-android-app/

Comment: I need to take pictures of a field. For example, the Drone will fly over an area taking pictures every seconds. I have a software that analyze the pictures to find object in them. Having video is not really possible because the object are "man" found and probably not ready for Google Vision API. (for example, detecting goose species in a picture where the goose are less than 1% of the image.

Comment: So it is really important to take pictures without user input. The application needs to take picture by itself, it doesn't even need to display the preview because it will be mounted on a flying Drone

Comment: There are lots of examples online for camera2. You could try this one and just remove all the visual parts: [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Camera2Basic/) just run the TakePicture function in a Thread that triggers it every second.